# double array loses its information

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am writing a little program with swing components for my class and I have a problem with storing information within a double array. The program works exactly as I want it with just one exception: I'm declaring an array via "public double [] noten;" outside the private methods of the actionlisteners. However the array is initiated inside the private method.

```
[...]
public double summe, notenschnitt;
public int i, anzahlnoten, besteNote, schlechtesteNote;
public double [] noten;


private void jBÜbernehmen2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        if(!jTAnzahlNoten.getText().equals("") && Double.parseDouble(jTAnzahlNoten.getText())>=1 
           && Double.parseDouble(jTAnzahlNoten.getText())<=5){

            i++; //Counts clicks

            DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

            summe = summe + Double.parseDouble(jTNote.getText()); //sum for calculating the mean

            anzahlnoten = Integer.parseInt(jTAnzahlNoten.getText()); //amount of grades

            noten = new double[anzahlnoten];
            noten[i-1] = Double.parseDouble(jTNote.getText());


            jLANoten.setText("Noten: ");
            jLANoten.setVisible(true);


            for(double ae: noten){
               jLANoten.setText(jLANoten.getText()+" "+ae);
            }

            notenschnitt = summe / i;

            jLBN.setVisible(true);
            jLNN.setVisible(true);
            jLSN.setVisible(true);
            jLNA.setVisible(true);

            jLNN.setText(f.format(notenschnitt));
            jLNA.setText(Integer.toString(i));
            jLNote.setText(i+". Note");

            if(Integer.parseInt(jTNote.getText()) < besteNote){
                //gets the best grade
                besteNote=Integer.parseInt(jTNote.getText());
                jLBN.setText(Integer.toString(besteNote));
            }

            if(Integer.parseInt(jTNote.getText()) > schlechtesteNote){ 
                //gets the worst grade
                schlechtesteNote=Integer.parseInt(jTNote.getText());
                jLSN.setText(Integer.toString(schlechtesteNote));
            }

            if (i >= Integer.parseInt(jTAnzahlNoten.getText())) { 
                //if clicks = amount of grades -> stop

                jBÜbernehmen2.setVisible(false);
                jBNeueBerechnung.setVisible(true);
                jTNote.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                jTNote.setFocusable(false);
            }else{
                jTNote.requestFocus();
                jTNote.setText("");
            }

        }


    }
[...]
```

this is not the whole code, just the crucial part

Expectation: the foreach loop is supposed to give the grades which i have entered.
Example: three grades should be entered and i enter 1,2 and 3. At the end the line should give: "Noten: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0"

But instead at the first click it gives: "Noten: 1.0, 0.0, 0.0". Second click: "Noten: 0.0, 2.0, 0.0" Third click: "Noten: 0.0, 0.0, 3.0".

It only prints the recent entered grade, but why ? The variable for the array is declared as public ?! I just don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep re-initializing the array before putting a new value in it :

```
        noten = new double[anzahlnoten];
        noten[i-1] = Double.parseDouble(jTNote.getText());
```

Make sure you only call `noten = new double[anzahlnoten];` once.

For example, you can initialize the array when you declare it :

```
public double [] noten = new double[someFixedLength];
```

Comment: Solution: don't re-create the array. Delete the top line. 1+

Comment: if i erase the above line i get a java.lang.NullPointerException :-/

Comment: @user4102425 You shouldn't erase it altogether, you should move it to a place where it will only be called once.

Comment: thaaanks it works now :-) i think i should take a closer look at initiations and stuff thx

Comment: of course it makes sence now. everytime i pressed the button the object was created new, which of course lost its previous information. the size was the same but the position due to i++ switched